# Building DLL with XML includes that are large

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, windows-7

I have 2 XML files that I would like to include into a project and compile as a .DLL

I have never had a problem with this before, well until my XML files significantly increased in size.

The one file is 475MB in size, if I compile with only this file, the DLL is complied without a problem. However, when I attempt to compile the file that is 700MB + then I get the common error.

> Unexpected error writing metadata to file  'Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.'

In the perfect situation I would like to be able to compile with the 700MB+ file and the 475MB file, but I would also need to know the limitations as I do expect the 700MB file to grow to well over a gigabyte.

Is there something I can do to get the DLL to build without giving me the errors? At this point I can not split the 700MB file up, I know that would be the perfect soultion but it is just not possible. Can anyone give me some advice about this?

I am running Windows 7 -64bit with 8 gigabytes of RAM and Visual Studio 2010 with no service pack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an article for VS.NET 2008 that might also apply to VS.NET 2010:

> "[Hacking Visual Studio to Use More Than 2Gigabytes of Memory](http://stevenharman.net/blog/archive/2008/04/29/hacking-visual-studio-to-use-more-than-2gigabytes-of-memory.aspx)"

Maybe this is also helpful for your issue.

Comment: worked like a bomb, thank you very much! although I would have imagined that with all the bugs from the previous versions they would have this sorted out long ago...